# Variable Price License for Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I would like to use the Chrome Web Store for the licensing for my Chrome Extension - but I need the ability to charge a different amount based on the user.  I have seen how to do a monthly subscription, but not how I could do variable licenses.  Any thoughts?